# HTML tables: horizontal scroll in a td only when needed

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, html-table, cell

I have a table with the following:

```
<table  cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" > 
<tr>
<td>Contact: </td>
<td width="100px"><div style="overflow-x:scroll; width:100px">ee@yahoo.com</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This code shows an horizontal scroll in the email cell.

When the email is a short one like ee@yahoo.com the scroll shows but it is not enabled as it is not needed, and when the email is longer let's say

eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee@yahoo.com

the scroll enables so you can see the entire email.

This is good, but what I need is the scroll not to show at all when the email is a short one.

How can I do that??

I've tried:

```
overflow-x:auto;
```

And it does not show the scroll when a short email but when the email is a long one it just cut it no scroll at all.  **I think this happens because there are no spaces in the email**.

Comment: Which browser are you using. This works fine for me in chrome. I would say you should try `overflow:auto` instead, as that is compatible with IE (if that is what you are using)

Comment: Yeah `overflow:auto` is working with all major browsers.

Comment: Create a fiddle duplicating your issue

Comment: Actually so is `overflow-x:auto`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By defining `overflow-x: scroll` you are indicating for a scroll bar to appear no matter what.

You should use `overflow-x:auto`. Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/2rEyt/)

Comment: believe or not, the problem is being caused by a font-size affecting the table. As soon as I delete the font-size the scroll auto works .. I'm puzzled

Answer (score 2):

works like a charm (IE9)

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" >  
    <tr> 
    <td>Contact: </td> 
    <td width="100px"><div style="overflow:auto; width:100px">ee@yahoo.com</div> 
    </td> 
    </tr> 
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fUW4s/1/

Comment: Rafael's solved a problem I was having, sort of. My table is in a flex column with two other columns. When I set td maxWidth to 50, 200, 300px, etc. I get correct appearance. If I set it to 600px, then the column gets stretched and all the text appears.